# Three type of Balls from Bag

Tags: c++11, math, probability

I have a problem which sounds like this:
We have a bag with balls in. There are R red balls, B blue balls and G green balls.
I need to find the minimum number of extractions from the bag such that i am sure that i will have at least K balls of same colour.

Anyone can help with any idea? Or tips, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `K>max(R,G,B)` then the problem has no solution. So let's assume `K <= max(R,G,B)`.

If you don't have any control over which ball gets extracted, you'll need *at most* (i.e. this is a lower bound) `min(R, (K-1))+min(G, (K-1))+min(B, (K-1))+1` extractions for obvious reasons: extract `K-1` red balls (or all red balls if `R<K`), then extract `K-1` green balls (or all green balls if `G<K`), and finally extract `K-1` blue balls (or all blue balls if `B<K`). Now there is at least one ball remaining---because `max(R,G,B)>=K` by assumption---and when we extract it we have `K` balls of the same color. (This is clearly the worst case.)

You obviously need at least `K` extractions (this is the best case).

Since you tagged the question with `probability`, maybe you can only extract a ball chosen uniformly at random. In that case we can talk of the expected number of extractions needed before we end up with `K` balls of the same color. This is an interesting question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it looks like there is a special case too, I have only 44 points with your conditions... :)

Comment: @Vader did I not answer your question? If you're more specific I can update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the upper bond working... When I test the upper bond, it blows off the int range (I using java)