# Find the minimum number of balls to take out from a bag containg balls of three types A,B,C, such that n number of balls are of same type

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinatorics

E.g. let us assume we have 1 ball of type A, 2 balls of type B, and 3 balls of type C in a bag. 
Then the minimum number of balls we have to take out from the bag in order to assure that at least 2 balls will be of the same type is "4" (one from each and firstly and 4th ball can be either of type B or C).

How can we find the same such that at least `n` number of balls are of the same type.

Comment: Your grammar is incorrect.  `e.g.` is an abbreviation for the Latin `exemple gratia` which means `for example`.  You were actually saying `for for example`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Or maybe it's a misspelling of *egg*, the prize you get for solving this puzzle.

Comment: To answer the only question actually, asked: *code* will eventually come into play. So.. [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: i tried brute forcing by subtracting one ball of each type until the n become  1 but it's not  working

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372859/three-type-of-balls-from-bag/36372904#36372904. (This is starting to smell like a homework problem. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

**tldr;** `-(2*N-2*N*M-3*M+M*M)/2`

---

If you have

```
A, 2B, 3C...
```

You may draw it like:

```
1    C B A
2    C B
3    C
```

Your minimum number for two will be filling lvl1 + 1

```
1   D C B A
2   D C B
3   D C
4   D
```

Now the minimum for 2 balls is  4 + 1 = 5, and  lvl 3 is 3 + 4 + 1 = 8

To reach lvl M having N letters, the loop is:

```
for (B=1,n=0; n<M-1; n++)
    B+=N-n;
```

---

The general math representation for that would be:

[image]

[That's equal to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

[image]

That can be expanded to:

```
-(2*N-2*N*M-3*M+M*M)/2
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to Solve this problem a simple approach will work. Just add up all the balls whose number is less than n (i.e. the minimum number of balls of same type). and then add up (n - 1) from all the remaining balls. Your answer will be the **sum + 1.**

Consider an example, lets say you have 10 balls of type A, 15 of type B, 20 of type C and you want to have at-least 16 balls of same color. The approach says to add up all the balls that count to less than n i.e. 16.. Hence sum is 10 + 15 = 25. Now add (n - 1) for all the remaining type of balls i.e. only type C. Hence sum = 40. Therefore the minimum balls you require to draw to have atleast 16 balls is **sum + 1 = 41**.